# map part of the vector efficiently in clojure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, vector, clojure

I wonder how this can be done in Clojure idiomatically and efficiently:

1) Given a vector containing n integers in it: [A<sub>0</sub> A<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> A<sub>3</sub> ... A<sub>n</sub>]

2) Increase the last x items by 1 (let's say x is 100) so the vector will become: [A<sub>0</sub> A<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> A<sub>3</sub> ... (A<sub>n-99</sub> + 1) (A<sub>n-98</sub> + 1)... (A<sub>n-1</sub> + 1) (A<sub>n</sub> + 1)]

One naive implementation looks like:

```
(defn inc-last [x nums]
  (let [n (count nums)]
      (map #(if (>= % (- n x)) (inc %2) %2)
           (range n) 
           nums)))

(inc-last 2 [1 2 3 4]) 
;=> [1 2 4 5]
```

In this implementation, basically you just map the entire vector to another vector by examine each item to see if it needs to be increased.

However, this is an O(n) operation while I only want to change the last x items in the vector. Ideally, this should be done in O(x) instead of O(n).

I am considering using some functions like split-at/concat to implement it like below:

```
(defn inc-last [x nums]
  (let [[nums1 nums2] (split-at x nums)]
    (concat nums1 (map inc nums2))))
```

However, I am not sure if this implementation is O(n) or O(x). I am new to Clojure and not really sure what the time complexity will be for operations like concat/split-at on persistent data structures in Clojure.

So my questions are:

1) What the time complexity here in second implementation?

2) If it is still O(n), is there any idiomatic and efficient implementation that takes only O(x) in Clojure for solving this problem?

Any comment is appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:**

noisesmith's answer told me that split-at will convert the vector into a list, which was a fact I did not realised previously. Since I will do random access for the result (call `nth` after processing the vector), I would like to have an efficient solution (O(x) time) while keeping the vector instead of list otherwise `nth` will slow down my program as well.

Comment: double checking your question, I was surprised to see that the implementation of split-at not only doesn't work in O(n) time (expected because it is implemented on non-associative datastructures), but it also walks the first (count - n) elements (or first n arguments in your version, actually inc-first) twice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inc-last` is an implementation using a `transient`, which allows to get a modifiable "in place" vector in constant time and return a `persistent!` vector also in constant time, which allows to make the updates in O(x).  **The original implementation used an imperative `doseq` loop but, as mentioned in the comments, transient operations can return a new object, so it's better to keep doing things in a functional way.**

I added a `doall` to the call to `inc-last-2` since it returns a lazy seq, but `inc-last` and `inc-last-3` returns a vector so the `doall` is needed to be able to compare them all.

According to some quick tests I made, `inc-last` and `inc-last-3` don't actually differ much in performance, not even for huge vectors (10000000 elements). For the `inc-last-2` implementation though, there's quite a difference even for a vector of 1000 elements, modifying only the last 10, it's ~100x slower. For smaller vectors or when the `n` is close to `(count nums)` the difference is not really that much.

*(Thanks to Michał Marczyk for his useful comments)*

```
(def x (vec (range 1000)))

(defn inc-last [n x]
  (let [x (transient x)
        l (count x)]
    (->>
      (range (- l n) l)
      (reduce #(assoc! %1 %2 (inc (%1 %2))) x)
      persistent!)))

(defn inc-last-2 [x nums]
  (let [n (count nums)]
    (map #(if (>= % (- n x)) (inc %2) %2)
         (range n) 
         nums)))

(defn inc-last-3 [n x]
  (let [l (count x)]
    (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (inc (%1 %2))) x (range (- l n) l))))

(time
  (dotimes [i 100]
    (inc-last 50 x)))

(time
  (dotimes [i 100]
    (doall (inc-last-2 10 x))))

(time
  (dotimes [i 100]
    (inc-last-3 50 x)))

;=> "Elapsed time: 49.7965 msecs"
;=> "Elapsed time: 1751.964501 msecs"
;=> "Elapsed time: 67.651 msecs"
```

Comment: It is important to note that transients are *not* meant to be bashed in place in imperative loops; you should still use them functionally (for example by replacing `assoc` with `assoc!` in `inc-last-3`, using a transient version of the vector as the accumulator for `reduce` and calling `persistent!` on the result). This is because transient operations may occasionally return new objects; this happens today with maps (when a transient array map gets converted to a transient hash map), and while it doesn't currently happen with vectors, Clojure makes no promises about this for the future.

Comment: Also, `inc-last-3` -- equivalent to noisesmith's `inc-last-n`  -- does not return a lazy seq; it returns a vector. In fact, it is a great functional solution; rewritten to use transients it would probably be optimal in terms of performance.

Comment: I didn't know that transient operations could return a new object. I will update the question replacing the imperative loop in `inc-last` for `reduce`.

Comment: You are right, the `inc-last-3` does return a vector (I don't know what I was thinking) and using `doall` on the result was causing the execution to take so long. `inc-last-3` is actually quite close to in performance to `inc-last`. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Even using `transient` / `persistent!`, you still operate in O(n) time because both imply copying the underlying size `n` arrays.

Comment: @omiel That's not true at all. Clojure's vectors are implemented as trees internally and all operations on them involve copying a single path from the root to a leaf and are O(log n), with very good constants. So in fact `inc-last-3` operates in time O(x log n), as do all similar approaches. Using transients appropriately improves the constant factors, but doesn't change the big-O complexity.

Comment: @juan.facorro No worries. One extra suggestion I'd make is to use [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) for benchmarking -- `time` is not a good fit for this purpose, even with the `dotimes` thrown in, because of the JIT compiler. A simple benchmark might look like `(require '[criterium.core :as c]) (c/bench (inc-last-3 50 x))`. Of course this wouldn't really change the conclusion in this case, it's just good policy in general.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk You are right. That was my initial assumption but I got confused re-reading the source code.

Answer (score 4):

Concat and split-at both turn the input into a seq, effectively a linked-list representation, O(x) time. Here is how to do it with a vector for O(n) performance.

```
user> (defn inc-last-n
        [n x]
        (let [count (count x)
              update (fn [x i] (update-in x [i] inc))]
          (reduce update x (range (- count n) count))))
#'user/inc-last-n
user> (inc-last-n 3 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6])
[0 1 2 3 5 6 7]
```

This will fail on input that is not associative (like seq / lazy-seq) because there is no O(1) access time in non-associative types.

Comment: Note that this is exactly what the question is asking for; that is, the O(n) of this answer is O(x) of the question (due to a different use of parameter names). This approach could be tweaked to use transients with a slightly more involved `update` function, and it would then use them correctly (that is, in a functional way).